# Changing attribute of an object inside LocalStorage?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

in my template I have an onclick-event, which is calling a method, that is supposed to change one attribute "status: boolean" of an object "eintrag" to true.

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="eintrag.status= !eintrag.status" onclick="changeStatus(eintrag)"/>
```

This object is inside an array `eintraege: Eintrag[] = [];` and is saved inside a LocalStorage     `this.eintragService.saveData('token', JSON.stringify(this.eintraege))`

Is there a way to implement changeStatus in a way, that I can change the attribute status in there and put it in the same index as it was, without deleting it? Or is it not possible with arrays?

Eintrag:

```
export interface Eintrag {
  beschreibung: string;
  status: boolean;
  faelligkeitsdatum: string;
}
```

For now, changeStatus is empty, all I do is finding the index of the "eintrag" inside the array:

```
this.eintrag = eintrag;
    const beschreibung = this.eintrag.beschreibung;
    const index = this.eintraege.findIndex(eintrag => eintrag.beschreibung === beschreibung);
```

Then I can delete the eintrag at the index, but I want it to be replaced there:

```
if (index > -1) {
  this.eintraege.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: the onclick-method already has the correct element, after that I'm using the findIndex method to get the index of the element in the array

Comment: Local storage is just a map. Just override the value

Comment: Also I also think that your approach is incorrect to use local storage as a runtime variable soteage. You should keep yoir data in the app normally and use local storage only to make it persistent beteween the sessions. So keep your data in memory and writr it tonlocal storage on save. When you reload your app, you read from the storage once to restore data into memory and the circle closes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface Eintrag {
  beschreibung: string;
  status: boolean;
  faelligkeitsdatum: string;
}

const eintraege: Eintrag[] = [
  { beschreibung: 'foo', status: false, faelligkeitsdatum: 'foo' },
  { beschreibung: 'bar', status: false, faelligkeitsdatum: 'bar' },
  { beschreibung: 'zoo', status: false, faelligkeitsdatum: 'zoo' },
];

/* the following line is meant to be executed just once, for the local
storage initialization, then it should be commented and only the 
updateEintraegeLocalStorage method to be executed for tests */

localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(eintraege));

const updateEintraegeLocalStorage = (elementIndexToUpdateStatus) => {
  let eintraege = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));

  const statusOfEintragToUpdate = eintraege[elementIndexToUpdateStatus]['status'];
  eintraege[elementIndexToUpdateStatus]['status'] = !statusOfEintragToUpdate;

  localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(eintraege));
};

/* index is a mock that you find in your code using
this.eintraege.findIndex(eintrag => eintrag.beschreibung === 
 beschreibung); 
*/
const index = 0;

updateEintraegeLocalStorage(index);
```